# PHP: How to make INVOKING internal functions faster

Tags: php, optimization, xdebug, xdebug-profiler, webgrind

I am trying to optimize a function that is called 560x during the execution of a request.

The function is this (some info redacted):

```
function foo($text) {
    if (preg_match('/[`"]/', $text)) {
        throw new Exception("very detailed error");
    }
    $text = explode('.', $text);
    $tick = '*';
    return $tick . implode("$tick.$tick", $text) . $tick;
}
```

Using XDEBUG PHP profiler + Webgrind, I see that these stats (in milliseconds) for this function:
[image]

As you can see, only 3ms is spent in `preg_match`, `explode`, `implode` *combined*. The other 20ms is spent just *invoking* these functions and concatenating some string. Is there a way I can reduce the total self cost of this function?

I have tried adding

```
use function preg_match;
use function explode;
use function implode;
```

as suggested [here](https://veewee.github.io/blog/optimizing-php-performance-by-fq-function-calls/), but I did not see any improvements. Any suggestions?

Comment: If 87% of the time is spent _invoking_ the function, why are we looking at the function?  I would consider ways to avoid calling the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to a more light-weight functions (but maybe losing some readability):

```
function foo($text) {
    if (strpos($text, '"')!==FALSE || strpos($text, '`')!==FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("very detailed error");
    }
    $tick = '*';
    return $tick . str_replace('.', "$tick.$tick", $text) . $tick;
}
```

Comment: Although logically this should decrease the latency, since it gets rid of the regex, it actually increases in practice by ~3ms  it since there is an additional function call.

There is a fixed-cost to a function call, other than the complexity of the actual function. This fixed cost is where most of the latency is coming from